How to get all possible indices of arrays as number union type?
How can I get all possible indices of array as number union type?
Expected result a number union type:
type VoiceSettings = {
    similarityLevel: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
    stabilityLevel: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
}

Actual result:
type VoiceSettings = {
    similarityLevel: "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4";
    stabilityLevel: "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4";
}

Code:
const VALUES_MAP = {
  similarityLevel: [0, 15, 30, 50, 75, 90],
  stabilityLevel: [15, 30, 60, 75, 90],
} as const;

type ValuesTypes = keyof typeof VALUES_MAP;

type VoiceSettings = {
  [key in ValuesTypes]: Exclude<keyof (typeof VALUES_MAP)[ValuesTypes], keyof []>;
};

Here's a TS playground

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Does this answer your question? Get index type of an array literal

Yes, it's amazing...could you please give an answer with explanation?

Do you still want me to give an answer in light of the existing answer from @DM below?

@jcalz yes please, it's a different approach

In TypeScript 4.8 and above you can convert arbitrary numeric string literal types into their numeric literal type counterparts, by using an extends constraint on an infer type variable inside a template literal type.
type StrToNum<T extends string> =
  T extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never

type X = StrToNum<"1" | "-7" | "3.14159">;
// type X = 1 | -7 | 3.14159

Once you do that it's easy enough to apply that to the numeric string indices of a tuple type (why they are stringish instead of numeric literals is ‍♂️, this is just how it's done):
type VoiceSettings = {
  -readonly [K in keyof ValuesMap]: (
    StrToNum<`${number}` & keyof ValuesMap[K]>
  )
};
/* type VoiceSettings = {
    similarityLevel: 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
    stabilityLevel: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
} */

By intersecting keyof ValuesMap[K] with `${number}` (a placeholder template literal) we are getting just those numeric-like strings.  You could do it your way, though and exclude keyof [].
Playground link to code

Clever! I hadn't really seen a generic use for infer, but this makes sense. Thanks for explaining.

From this answer on the question I proposed as a duplicate:

You can use the following type:
type Indices<T extends readonly any[]> = Exclude<Partial<T>["length"], T["length"]>


Which, for your problem, looks like this:
const VALUES_MAP = {
  similarityLevel: [0, 15, 30, 50, 75, 90],
  stabilityLevel: [15, 30, 60, 75, 90],
} as const;

type ValuesTypes = keyof typeof VALUES_MAP;

type Indices<T extends readonly any[]> = Exclude<Partial<T>["length"], T["length"]>

type VoiceSettings = {
  [K in ValuesTypes]: Indices<typeof VALUES_MAP[K]>;
};

Where VoiceSettings is typed as:
type VoiceSettings = {
  similarityLevel: 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
  stabilityLevel: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
}

Here's a TS Playground

Please consider replacing key with Key or K. It's a generic type parameter, not a key name or variable.

I'm trying to not use any type at all cost. Might be I'm wrong and it's okay? I saw this solution before posting...but because of any[] don't tried it.

T extends readonly unknown[] works just as well. It's just saying that the type parameter for Indices must be a readonly array. We don't care what's in the array. The type information isn't useful after Indices<T> because we've reduced the array to just its indices... which are always number.

wow, Exclude<Partial<T>["length"], T["length"]> is pretty slick!
